# Leer varias lineas de un archivo de texto JAVA

Tags: java

Necesito poder leer varias lineas de un .txt con un formato especifico por linea `(String, int, int)` por ejemplo `(Erick, 99,88)`.

Después de eso hacer un split de cada línea, usando como parámetro para el split una coma, para poder operar con los dos números enteros de cada línea. Avancé con el siguiente​ código, pero sólo me logra imprimir la 2da línea y no tengo idea del porqué.

```
File file = new File("Calificaciones.txt");

FileReader fileR = null;
BufferedReader file2 = null;

try {
    fileR = new FileReader(file);
    file2 = new BufferedReader(fileR);


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("No se encontro el archivo "+file.getName());
}

try {
    while(file2.readLine() != null)
        {
            String lines = file2.readLine();
            System.out.println(lines);
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ¿y en qué parte estás intentando un Split por comas? ¿Cuál es el objetivo? ¿llevarlo a 2 variables int o qué?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza listo gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias a ti por estar atento y presto :D. Espero que continúes participando en el sitio

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza a uds, por su ayuda tan eficaz, creo que seria buena idea mostrar el código final por si a alguien le es de utilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta si esta modificación te funciona asi estan en todos los ejemplos: [Leer ficheros en java](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/leer-fichero-de-texto-con-java/)

```
File file = new File("Calificaciones.txt");
FileReader fileR = null;
BufferedReader file2 = null;

try {
    fileR = new FileReader(file);
    file2 = new BufferedReader(fileR);


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("No se encontro el archivo "+file.getName());
}

try {
    String lines = "";
    while( ( lines = file2.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(lines);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sólo cambia la parte del While y ahora escríbela de la siguiente forma'

```
String lines;
while((lines=file2.readLine())!=null)
            {

                System.out.println(lines);
            }
```